# Materialize Design Hamburger Icon Not Displaying

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, material-design, materialize

I'm using materialize as a UI framework in my rails app, and everything is working correctly except the 'material-icons' 'menu' option isn't working properly.

The full code is further below, but this is the piece that is not working appropriately:

```
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

Instead of turning into a hamburger icon, when I shrink the browser to trigger the responsiveness, it just displays the text node 'menu'. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Everything else is working.

This is the entire nav/dropdown structure:

```
  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">My Courses</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">My Courses</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>

  <header>
    <nav class="z-depth-2">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">OppSim</a>
          <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <!-- web view -->
            <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">JTB<i class="material-icons right"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
          <!-- mobile view -->
            <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown2">JTB<i class="material-icons right"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Or maybe I should stick with golf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use icons in materalize you have to include this font

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

as per their official documentation [here](http://materializecss.com/icons.html)

Comment: Thanks Peter, I must have glanced past that. Thought I had everything already. I appreciate this!